# Why isn't my Entity Framework Code First Pluralization working?

Tags: ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework Code First.  Usually I have no problem, but for a database I'm working with I keep getting errors that it can't find the table in the SQL Server database.  Here is what my class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class CustomApp_User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

}
```

In the database I have a table called "CustomApp_Users" to match the above.  Note it has the "s" at the end.

And then I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

public class CustomAppDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CustomApp_User> CustomApp_Users { get; set; }
}
```

I expected EF codefirst to pluralize so that it would find "CustomApp_Users" in the database since this is how it usually works.  But instead I get the error:

Invalid object name 'dbo.CustomApp_User'.

It appears it's not pluralizing the table name.  I can't figure out why.  One thing different with this database is that the Primary Keys do not follow the normal convention so I use the [Key] annotation.

I do know that if I use the [Table] annotation for my class it will work:
[Table("CustomApp_Users")]

But, I'd like to find out why the pluralization is not working the way I thought it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the [PluralizationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx) in EF can not pluralize it. It returns the same string if you pass it "CustomApp_User". Unfortunately you can not customize this service. So you need to configure the table name explicitly.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know we could call the PluralizationService.  It seems if the table name has a an underscore in it then it won't pluralize it.  If I take out the underscore it pluralizes.  I wonder why they did that?

Comment: @metanaito Maybe because it is not a good practice to use `_` marks in class names.

Comment: I have never heard that before.  I'm wondering then, perhaps I should change my "CustomApp_User" naming to "CustomAppUser" just to make everything consistent and work together. That would solve my pluralization issue as well, though I kind of like explicitly defining the table name.  Not too sure if this naming will cause confusion down the line somewhere.