# Is there a known issue with Code First default mapping on a table with 'Statuses' suffix

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have the following code in my context, and no explicit table-class mapping, yet my database keeps getting created (by my `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer) with an `EmployeeStatus` table, not `EmployeeStatuses`. Is there a known issue with this, or am I going insane or what?

```
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeeStatus> EmployeeStatuses { get; set; }
```

All my other tables are named exactly after their DbSet names, as I expect.

Comment: You are using Code-First, why should you care? :) I believe, that mapper just give the Entity class name to the table, not the property name.

Comment: Take a look at [Why isn't my Entity Framework Code First Pluralization working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557879/why-isnt-my-entity-framework-code-first-pluralization-working/8558091#8558091)

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov I need to care because I run seeding scripts that reference the table by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework uses its [pluralization service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx) to infer database table names based on
the class names in the model—**Destination** becomes **Destinations**, **Person** becomes
**People**, etc. By convention, Code First will do its best to pluralize the class name and use the results as the name of the table. However, it might not be the same as your
table naming conventions.

You can use the **Table** Data Annotation to ensure that Code First maps your class to
the correct table name.

Comment: The irony here being I actually prefer singular names personally.